# phonegap in android

Tags: android

hi i want to install phone gap in android.
i had done lots of try from net but not install correct way.
so plz help me if u know..............Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information you need is [in their page](http://www.phonegap.com/start#android). You need to create an eclipse project as if you were creating an android project, include their packages and point to the directory were you have your web app files. Carefully read the instructions and you'll be able to do it.

Comment: plz Explin More specific. I can not Understand. i had already install eclips with their componats.

Comment: better than the instructions in their site is just having someone do it for you so either read everything thoroughly and try to solve it or ask someone to show it to you. There's no better explanation than the one from phonegap's site.